# JPA: @JoinTable - Both columns are Primary Keys.. How do I stop that?

Tags: jpa, primary-key, one-to-many, join

This is my annotation I use to generate my Join Table.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "service_operations", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "serviceId") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "operationId") })
public Set<Operation> getOperations() {
    return operations;
}
```

Considering this is a OneToMany association, my natural assumption is that this table would generate a

[ Primary Key | Foreign Key ] table, however everytime I drop and re create the database it is not the case:

```
mysql> describe workflow_services;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| workflow_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| service_id  | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Im a tad baffled by this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What Behrang said below, plus: MySQL's `describe` doesn't show foreign keys; but both `workflow_id` and `service_id` most definitely are FKs on their respective tables. Also, JPA *correctly* defined a compound primary key on both columns here, i.e. both columns are *part of* the tables PK and each on its own is (the single part of) a FK.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my problem by adding the following changes:

I changed my @OneToMany to a @ManyToMany annotation

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "workflow_services", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"))
public Set<Service> getServices() {
    return services;
}
```

I added a Set workflows; association in my Service object

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="services")  // map info is in person class
public Set<Workflow> getWorkflows() {
    return workflows;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks correct to me. Each row in the join table should identify a pair of workflow/service items. So `(workflow_id, service_id)` should be the primary key. Also `workflow_id` should be a foreign key into the `workflow` table and `service_id` should be a foreign key into the `service` table.

Also note that a one-to-many association between A and B does not mean that an instance of A can have the same instance of B multiple times, rather an instance of A can have multiple distinct instances of B. For example a blog `Post` entity can have a one-to-many association with a `Tag` entity. This means that a blog `Post` P1 can have multiple tags `Java`, `JPA`, `JavaEE`, but can not have the same tag multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this however I am still in need of an answer to my issue.  Would I shift to a @ManyToMany annotation or is thee something else I must do to get a table that results in:

`[ 1 | 3 ]
[ 1 | 4 ]
[ 2 | 3 ]`   <-- 2 workflows have an association with the same service

Comment: @DreamsInStereo `[1 | 3]` and `[1 | 4]` can be persisted in the current table as the primary keys are `(1, 3)` and `(1, 4)` and they are unique. You can have as many associations as you like: `(1, 2)`, `(1, 3)`, `(1, 4)`, `(1, 5)`, ...

Comment: I am not seeking unique Service id's.  I am seeking multiple Workflows pointing at the same service.

The workflow_id column must remain unique however the service_Id column must NOT be unique.  

Am I to use a Many To Many to get the second FK column to be non unique?

Comment: What I believe I want is a 

workflow_id + service_id COMPOSITE key where service_id is NOT Primary.