# Hibernate: HashMap<EntityA, EntityB> annotation mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hashmap, jpa-2.0

I am relatively new to Hibernate but I have bumped on this, probably simple problem, but I was unable to solve it anyway. I want to map entity containing java Map field, which should (of course) behave like java map in this persisted POJO object. For simplicity of question, I made entites as simple as I could so that main problem could still be recognized.

So there are 3 entities in total:

## EntityA (used as key in map):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_A")
public class EntityA implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@Column
private String valueA;
}
```

## EntityB (used as value in map):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_B")
public class EntityB implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@Column
private String valueB;
}
```

## MainEntity (containing map field):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN_ENTITY")
public class MainEntity implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="ENTITYA_ENTITYB",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ENTITY_MAIN"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ENTITY_B", unique=false),
    uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ENTITY_MAIN", "ENTITY_A"}))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="ENTITY_A")
private Map<EntityA, EntityB> entityMap;
}
```

This annotation mapping for a map is the best solution i found so far. And actually, almost everything is as desired, except one small detail - map persisted this way is not acting like map. Because when Hibernate generates this join table in underlying DB(PostgreSQL), there is one problematic constraint (among others that are ok: 1 primary key for entity_main and entity_a in combination, and 3 more for 3 foreign keys) that prevents this map from working normally:

```
ALTER TABLE entitya_entityb ADD CONSTRAINT uk_5bbk6m10bx6ru2wh2gtrlpbqr UNIQUE(entity_b);
```

This effectively prevents this map from having the same object(EntityB) for a map value (and not only for one MainEntity map, but for all persisted maps) . So i can't put same EntityB as value for different key(EntityA) in a map and persist it. I always get error about this constraint:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_5bbk6m10bx6ru2wh2gtrlpbqr" Detail: Key (entity_b)=(3) already exists.
```

I have tried (as shown above) with unique=false for inverseJoinColumns, but no luck. I also tried other things which are probably even more wrong than this one so i won't post them here :-/

I will also post picture of expectations here, so i make this more clear:

[image: desired join table look]

So.. what did I do wrong? Why my mapped HashMap can't behave like simple java map? At first i was thinking this must be something obvious because, anyone mapping hashmap in hibernate would expect that map behaves correctly. But then i figured out that I actually cant find my answer on SO or anywhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone bump on this or similar problem.. I found a solution eventually.
It was actually explained in another SO question but I was unable to find it initially.

It was only a matter of changing @OneToMany to @ManyToMany annotation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7637117/1943765